# Exit the script whenever i close spesific program || AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

First, Here's the code

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#SingleInstance Force
IfWinNotExist, ahk_exe VisualBoyAdvance.exe
{
    Run, VisualBoyAdvance.exe, D:\Games\GAMEBOY ADVANCE (.gba)\GBA\emu
    WinWait, ahk_exe VisualBoyAdvance.exe
    WinActivate, ahk_exe VisualBoyAdvance.exe
    return
}
WinActivate, ahk_exe VisualBoyAdvance.exe
sleep, 1000
MouseClick,,22,40
sleep,100
MouseClick,,116,257
sleep,100
MouseClick,,342,312
sleep,100
MouseClick,,179,16
return
Joy4::
MouseClick,,77,43
sleep, 100
MouseClick,,111,105
sleep, 100
MouseClick,,263,217
sleep, 100
MouseMove, 1380, 251
return
Joy1::
Send, {Shift Down}
Sleep, 100
Send, {F1}
Sleep, 100
Send, {Shift Up}
Return
Joy12::Send, {F1}
return
;LCtrl::
;ExitApp
```

It's basically open VisualBoyAdvance from the top of the recent list on VBA, i wanted to whenever i close the VBA, the script closed as well.. i've tried lot of method on the AutoHotKey Website, like :
    Process, WaitClose, exwfile.exe
    ExitApp
    Return
Or

```
RunWait, calc
ExitApp
```

or

```
Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Sonos\Sonos.exe
WinWait, ahk_exe Sonos.exe
SetTimer,Sonos,100

Sonos:
IfWinNotExist, Sonos
     ExitApp
Return
```

but none of them works

please help me
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`WinWaitClose`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitClose.htm) followed by [`ExitApp`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ExitApp.htm):

```
// [...]
sleep,100
MouseClick,,179,16
WinWaitClose, ahk_exe VisualBoyAdvance.exe
ExitApp
Return

// [...]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
IfWinNotExist, ahk_exe Sonos.exe
```